# Problem running PHP temperature converter

Tags: php

I've been trying to work a simple form-based temperature converter, but I'm currently getting a white screen, and I cannot see what is wrong with the code. In addition, any ideas / suggestions for best practice are most welcome!

```
<?php // convert.php

if (isset($_POST['temperature']))   
    $temp = sanitize_string($_POST['temperature']);

if (isset($_POST['scale']))
{
    if ($_POST['scale'] == 'fah')
        $conv = 'fah';
        $output = intval((5 / 9) * ($temp - 32));
    elseif ($_POST['scale'] == 'cel')
        $conv = 'cel';
        $output = intval((9 / 5) * ($temp + 32));
    else
        $output = '';
}
?>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Temperature converter</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['submitted']) and isset($conv))
    {
        if ($conv == 'fah')
            print("$temp degrees Fahrenheit is $output degrees Celcius");
        elseif ($conv == 'cel')
            print("$temp degrees Celcius is $output degrees Fahrenheit");
    }
    ?>

<form method="post" action="convert.php">
    <label>Temperature <input type="text" name="temperature"></label>
    <label>Celcius <input type="radio" name="scale" value="cel"></label>
    <label>Fahrenheit <input type="radio" name="scale" value="fah"></label>
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="yes">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>

</html>

<?php
print_r($_POST);

function sanitize_string($var)
{
    $var = stripslashes($var);
    $var = htmlentities($var);
    $var = strip_tags($var);
    return $var;
}
?>
```

Comment: Turn on error reporting in your `php.ini`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to use curly braces on the inner if/elseif on line 11. It should look like the following:

```
if (isset($_POST['scale']))
{
    if ($_POST['scale'] == 'fah') {
        $conv = 'fah';
        $output = intval((5 / 9) * ($temp - 32));
    }
    elseif ($_POST['scale'] == 'cel') {
        $conv = 'cel';
        $output = intval((9 / 5) * ($temp + 32));
    }
    else
        $output = '';
}
```

Try to avoid the shorthand if-syntax where you can leave off the curly braces.

Comment: I didn't recognize it at first glance either (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Your `$conv` variable is only visible inside those if-statements. Add its declaration right on top:

```
<?php
$conv = null;
// your code
```

And then check `if (isset($_POST['submitted']) && $conv !== null)`

**Edit:** As @halfdan said, you are missing curly braces since you want to execute more than one statement in the if-else-clauses.

Comment: That doesn't seem to make a difference, does $var need to be declared for isset($var) to work?

Comment: Have you tried it? Scope is scope, if you only define it inside those if statements, `isset($conv)` will always return `false` outside...

Answer (score 1):

You have mismatched conditionals.

You're getting a blank screen because parsing your script fails and you have error reporting turned off.

Answer (score 1):

Your formulas are also wrong.
98.6 degrees F converts to 37 C
but 32 degrees C converts to 115 F.

Something is definitely wrong there.

First, converting from Fahrenheit to Celsius, you are adding 32 before you multiply by 9/5. That is WRONG. You must first multiply the Fahrenheit temp by 9/5; then add the 32.

So this line:
$output = intval((9 / 5) * ($temp + 32));
Should actually be
$output = intval((9/5) * ($temp) + 32);

I don't know how exact you want your conversions to be, but I'd also avoid using "intval." That is rounding your conversions to integer values.

Answer (score 0):

Use $searchengine to find pages about "php white page", and you'll get:

- http://drupal.org/node/158043
- http://php.about.com/od/troubleshooting/f/white_page_php.htm